# Parsing a Millisecond Timestamp To a Time In R

Tags: r, datetime, time-series

I'm this has been asked before, but I just can't find the exact answer.
If I have a number which represents milliseconds since midnight, say 34200577, how do I turn this into an R time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Construct a 'baseline time' at midnight, add the given millisecond *once converted to seconds* and interpret as a time:

```
R> as.POSIXct(as.numeric(ISOdatetime(2013,8,22,0,0,0)) + 34200577/1e3, 
+             origin="1970-01-01")
[1] "2013-08-22 09:30:00.576 CDT"
R>
```

In fact, the shorter

```
R> ISOdatetime(2013,8,22,0,0,0) + 34200577/1e3
[1] "2013-08-22 09:30:00.576 CDT"
R>
```

works as well as `ISOdatetime()` returns a proper time object *which operates in fractional seconds* so we just apply the given offset.

This appears to be correct as

```
R> 34200577/1e3       # seconds
[1] 34200.6
R> 34200577/1e3/60    # minutes
[1] 570.01
R> 34200577/1e3/60/60 # hours
[1] 9.50016
R>
```

Comment: Pleasure. Please feel free to accept and/or upvote as is common the site.

Answer (score 2):

POSIXct uses 1970 as the origin of its time scale(measured in seconds.)

```
> time= as.POSIXct(34200577/1000 , origin=Sys.Date() )
> time
[1] "2013-08-22 02:30:00 PDT"
```

Note the discrepancy in results between Dirk's and my method. The POSIX times are input as assumed to occur in UCT, so there appeared the addition 8 hours for my location in UCT-8.

```
> difftime( as.POSIXct(34200577/1000 , origin=Sys.Date() ) , Sys.Date() )
Time difference of 9.50016 hours
```

You could get the time since midnight with:

```
 format( as.POSIXct(34200577/1000 , origin=Sys.Date(), tz="UCT" ),
          format="%H:%M:%S")
 [1] "09:30:00"
```

Comment: David, OP said _milliseconds since midnight_ so you miss a 10^-3 scale factor.

Comment: There is a seven hour delta between our answers. Only one can be right. I fear you are missing a `TZ` conversion somewhere.

Comment: Right. I left in the discrepancy in to highlight the issue for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

A little "gottcha" which I think is worth pointing out...

In R 3.1.2 on windows 64 bit I get the following results for Dirk's example

```
> ISOdatetime(2013,8,22,0,0,0) + 34200577/1e3
[1] "2013-08-22 09:30:00 BST"
```

Note the lack of fractional seconds. This is due to the option setting for "digits.secs"

```
> getOption("digits.secs")
NULL
```

Setting this option as follows gives the expected result:

```
> options(digits.secs=3)
> ISOdatetime(2013,8,22,0,0,0) + 34200577/1e3
[1] "2013-08-22 09:30:00.576 BST"
```

As you can probably guess, this is to do with the formatting of output, not the actual values we get from our date arithmetic. See `?strptime` and `?options` for the documentation on this.