# 16 digits timestamp to date conversion in R

Tags: sql, r, datetime, type-conversion

How can I convert 16 digits milliseconds time stamp of mobile in R to actual date- time value. For e.g 1492797425516875

Comment: This might help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392809/parsing-a-millisecond-timestamp-to-a-time-in-r

Comment: Try `as.POSIXct(1492797425516875/1e6,origin="1970-01-01")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
> library(anytime)
> anytime(1492797425516875/1e6)
[1] "2017-04-21 23:27:05 IST"
```